# Maximum nonintersecting interval pick

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, algorithms

This surely has been solved in the context of scheduling already! (Shall I ask on some computer SE instead?)

Assume we have a set of closed "intervals" on $\mathbb Z$ ($\mathbb R$ isn't different, I guess) and like to pick the maximum cardinality of nonintersecting intervals from it. I bet the obvious greedy algorithm (first throw out all intervals that completely enclose another, then pick leftmost, repeat) already gives the solution.

A reference would suffice. (If the proof is trivial, please leave it to me :-)

Comment: Is this it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling

Comment: Bingo and THX! I admit I could have found that myself if I wanted to and weren't too lazy (those summer temperatures :-). Question can be closed, I can find the original literature with a formal proof of the greedy algorithm myself.